# Google Analytics Dashboard Widget for Event Category and Event Label

Tags: google-analytics

I have a requirement where I need to display the Event Label, Event Category across the label and Total Events for the same in one dashboard Widget. 
For eg:
[image]

How can I achieve this in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Aditya,
This table can't be achieved in a dashboard but can be setup in a custom report.

Comment: @AnalyticsMi can i achieve something similar with the eCommerce

Comment: please do suggest something similar to for ecommerce